# Apache rewrite from root folder, force https

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect traffic from mysite.com to mysite.com/folder, but also enforce SSL on all pages.

Currently we have this in httpd.conf we found from a sample somewhere, but I don't think that it is working correctly all of the time.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/$ https://www.mysite.com/folder/ [R]
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^/$` only matches if the request is for exactly `/`, i.e. the root of the site. Anything else is not matched by it. Try `.*` instead.

Note: if this rewrite rule is active for both the HTTP and the HTTPS version, that'll send you into an infinite redirect loop. In that case, you may need some kind of RewriteCond test, too.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, so the second line should look like this?    RewriteRule .* https://www.mysite.com/folder/ [R] I know next to nothing about Apache configurations. I am going to assume that this applies to HTTP and HTTPS since it is not contained in any special virtual host statements or anything.

Comment: Yeah. If you need any extra examples, there are plenty in Apache's URL rewriting guide. Good luck! PS. the HTTP-and-HTTPS thing will be an issue. If you don't find an example in the guide to take care of problems with that, ping me again and I'll get back to you. It might take quite some time, though.